# How to force to complete response in controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I need to make some slow operations on controller action. But it's not necessary to wait this operation for response rendering.

```
class ProductController < ActionController
  def update
    slow_operations()
    render json: {status: 'ok'}
  end
end
```

Even I move my code after `render` in Product#update action, it's not reduces response time.

```
class ProductController < ActionController
  def update
    render json: {status: 'ok'}
    slow_operations()
  end
end
```

How to force to return complete response before executing of slow operations?

Comment: off the top of my head you could add a job to a queue to be done later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way Rails works, it's still going to do the actual "rendering" after the action is complete - so, as you found out, moving "render" higher in your action doesn't help.  What you need to do is shuffle off the long-running operation into a background process.  There's lots of gems to do this, including [BackgroundRb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org), [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) (my personal favourite, largely because it is multi-threaded, cutting down on the number of processes you need to start, and because of its nice web-based admin/monitoring interface).

There's even a Railscast to get you started for most of these, like this one: http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate something like [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [Girl Friday](http://mperham.github.com/girl_friday/) to offload the slow process to a background task.